# ORA-00942 table or view does not exist when I run a package using a cursor

Tags: oracle

I get a weird error when running an Oracle page, which needs to find an existing tablespace to create a new schema. I am using an AWS RDS Oracle instance using 19c. The package compiles without errors.

Package

```
...
ts_name varchar2(30); 

sql_stmt varchar2(255); 

procedure create_schema (input in varchar2);
```

Package Body

```
procedure create_schema (input in varchar2) as 

v_cur SYS_REFCURSOR; 
v2_cur SYS_REFCURSOR; 

BEGIN 
    usrname := input; 
    ts_name := substr(input,0,30));
    sql_stmt := 'select ts# from v$tablespace where name = '''||ts_name||''''; 

    OPEN v_cur FOR sql_stmt;
    ...
```

When I run it, I get this error:

> ORA-00942: table or view does not exist
> ORA-06512: at "mypackage", line 13

Line 13 is the *OPEN v_cur FOR* line. Manually, I can run `select ts# from v$tablespace` without any issues.  No clue why this happens. Can someone explain the non-existing table/view?

Comment: First, I'm not sure why you're using dynamic SQL here. Second, I'll wager that the owner of the stored procedure has aces to `v$tablespace` via a role rather than via a direct grant. You would need a direct grant if you want to reference it in a definer's rights stored procedure.

Comment: Thanks for the reason. Finally replaced it with `sqlplus user@instance @create_user_and_tablespace.sql`